# Can i stay with my Schengen visa after my residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen

I entered on a multi entrance Schengen visa in February 2022, which is valid until the summer of 2024. Then in April, I obtained a one-year student residence permit for Spain until April 2023. Can I continue to stay in the EU on my Schengen visa after my resident permit expired? If so, for how long? How are the 90 days calculated based on my Schengen visa in this case?